# Avoiding Proxy Server by using Unix for Domain Controller?

Tags: permissions, security, proxy

Am wondering if Unix can be set to avoid a Proxy Server (Middle-man attack) that has likely been physically established on a cable internet line at the pole (via a physical, "jumper," or similar.

I am connecting to the internet through a cable modem that does not have WiFi capability.

Questions:

- Can Unix be set up as a Domain Controller to route traffic through a Proxy setup like this?
- Can Unix be used to deny traffic to or from a Proxy Server and connect only DIRECTLY to a known legit IP or web address? Random internet surfing is not required.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: This is not the place for political discussions. Keep the comments about the _technical_ aspects of the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Is this likely?

It's an interesting point.  There may be attacks still viable this way today (in 2022), but they have got much harder and less effective over the past decade.

The reason being, that cheap ([free](https://letsencrypt.org/)) encryption is so easily available that most services are now encrypted.  This means that your browser will open an encrypted channel with the webserver and then ask the webserver to prove it is authorised to act as the domain name you connect to.

A "man in the middle" could:

- open an encrypted channel with you but would then fail to prove it's authorised as the website you want (*useless*)
- record *encrypted* traffic between you and the server, but would be unable to decrypt it so would be unable to know what was actually sent. (*useless [until scientists crack quantum computing](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-60144498)*)
- in a *really really really* limited way detect what type of protocol is being sent over the encrypted channel.  For example China's [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) can apparently detect if an encrypted channel is being used as a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (yes/no) by analysing packet lengths / timings without decrypting them. (*useless [except to Chinese authorities](https://www.travelchinacheaper.com/vpns-still-work-china)*)

The IP addresses and Domain names you connect to may be exposed under normal browsing but that's about it.

Check for the little padlock in your browser next to the domain name.  If that's there then the chances are that a man-in-the-middle attack can't snoop on what you're browsing there.

**The one risk...** if someone can trick you into installing a new [CA Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) onto your computer, then that computer might then be at risk of a man-in-the-middle attack.  That's because your computer will then trust the hacker as if they are a Certificate Authority.

### What's not Possible

> Am wondering if Unix can be set to avoid a Proxy Server (Middle-man attack) that has likely been physically established on a cable internet line at the pole (via a physical, "jumper," or similar.

"Avoid" as in simply route past?  No.  Most likely not.  The reason being there may no longer be any connection that doesn't go through the attacker's device.

There's a small chance that an attack could have been performed by a less invasive means of spoofing your ISP's DHCP server.  This could be used to re-configure your cable modem (router) to use the wrong default-gateway address and / or DNS servers.  The only evidence for this would be on your cable modem (router) and nothing on your home network would be able to detect it.

Theoretically it may be possible to re-configure your cable modem to avoid a DHCP attack like this (hard-coding the DNS and Default gateway).  However that doesn't protect you much if the attacker has actually managed to physically re-wire your internet.

> Can Unix be used to deny traffic to or from a Proxy Server and connect only DIRECTLY to a known legit IP or web address? Random internet surfing is not required.

A man-in-the-middle attack like you describe may not change any IP addresses unless it's spoofing your DNS servers.

That said it is possible to use iptables firewall rules to limit incoming traffic to just a hand full of "known" IP addresses.  I won't give examples here because I don't think it's genuinely effective.

### What protection is possible.

The one thing that could could avoid a localised attack like this would be to use a properly set up encrypted VPN.  This would route *all* of your internet traffic over an encrypted channel to a VPN server.  This moves the problem to the security of the VPN server.

If you are concerned you may also like to look up "TOR".